# Accessing JSON in Angular2

Tags: json, angular

I'm having a tough time understanding how to access different aspects of an JSON object in Angular2. Particularly, I have a web API that I built that returns the following JSON object regarding the hard drive details on my server:

[image]

The image is a screenshot of my console in Chrome after using an httpService and Observable to push it to the console but understanding how to get to a specific piece of info is getting lost on me.

If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You already got the data. What exactly do you want to achieve? if you want to get the available space you have to use *retrievedObject.Data[0].AvailableSpace*

Comment: Show how do you subscribe to Observable.

Comment: check for the syntax for ajax hit http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-and-http

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having subscribed to the http Observable you have already got the actual object.
Assuming your http get request looks like this:

`this.httpService.get(this.apiUrl);`

you can use the power of rxjs Observables, for example map over the object like this:

`this.httpService.get(this.apiUrl)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .map(body => body.Data)
  .map(data => data[0].AvailableSpace)`

which after `subscribing` to would return the `AvailableSpace`.

`.subscribe(availablespace => console.log(availablespace);`

Watch out for accessing arrays like this, this is just to give you an example on how to access and manipulate objects in observables.

Check this site out for more information on different observable 
operators, other than `map`.
https://www.learnrxjs.io/

Comment: Thank you Alexander, your post made sense and reading up at learnrxjs.io helped me understand how to bring that info into my HTML (specifically into a div), as opposed to the console.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try my luck. Hope it will help people understand better. Particularly, I will talk about how to perform **get** request in Angular 2. It is always better to have a **get** and **post** request in a separate file called **service.ts** as mentioned in the official documentation.

We will have three files, namely **example.component.ts**, **example.service.ts** and Model file **examplemodel.ts**

**example.component.ts**

```
import {OnInit, Component} from "@angular/core";
import {ExampleService} from "./example.service"; // import service
import {ResponseFromGet, ErrorMessage} from "./examplemodel"; // import your model
@Component({
  providers: [ExampleService], // add your service here in order to use in component file
  templateUrl: './example.template.html'
})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit{
 //Specify Url for Get request
 Private _getRequestUrl = "http://entergetrequesturlhere";

// Make variable for stroing get method reponse which can be used in ur template file
 responseFromGetMethod: ResponseFromGet; // this can be ur model file which represnts ur JSON model

// For storing Error
  errorMessage: ErrorMessage;

//use Constructor to inject your service in component file
constructor(private _exampleService: ExampleService){}

// Since we implemented OnInit we need to override its method ngOnInit
// this method is called when page is loaded
  ngOnInit(): any{
    this.callGetMethod(this._getRequestUrl);
  }

// callGetMethod outside OnInit but inside class ExampleComponent
  callGetMethod(getUrl: string){
    this._exampleService.getMethodName(getUrl)
      .subscribe(
         responseFromGetMethod => {
           this.responseFromGetMethod = responseFromGetMethod; // Store response from getmethod in your local variable
         },
         error => this.errorMessage = <any>error // Store error message receiver from server
         );
  }
}
```

**example.service.ts**

```
import {Http, Response} from "@angular/http";
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import {ResponseFromGet} from "./examplemodel";
@Injectable()
export class ExampleService{
   constructor(private _http: Http) { }

   // GET request To access data and specify observable type from model
  getMethodName(getUrl): Observable<ResponseFromGet>{
    return this._http.get(getUrl)
     .map(this.extractData) // to check for the status code
     .catch(this.handleError); // to check error
  }

  // Extracts from response
  private extractData(res: Response) {
     if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
       throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
     }
     let response = res.json();
     return response || {};
  }

  // To handle Error
  private handleError(error: Response) {
     console.error(error);
     return Observable.throw(error.json() || 'Server error');
  }
}
```

**examplemodel.ts**

```
export interface ResponseFromGet{
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
export interface ErrorMessage{
  message: string;
}
```

And finally the HTML file
**example.template.html**

```
<div>
  <h2>{{responseFromGetMethod?.name}}</h2> // this will print the name from the json file
  <h3>{{errorMessage?.message}}</h3> // this will print the error if any
</div>
```

Lastly, this is the model of my **JSON** file

```
{
  "id": 789;
  "name": "Angular2";
}
```